# Регулярное выражение для nginx access.log

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Какой подход более правильный при составлении регулярного выржения, которое отлавливало бы все записи в `access.log` *NGINX*, у которых поле `Referrer:` содержит `bs.serving-sys.com`?

Пример записи с этим полем:

> 174.109.109.115 www.auctiondirectusa.com - [01/Oct/2015:09:38:24 -0500] "GET /used-cars-raleigh-nc?utm_source=TU+MEDIA&utm_medium=MOBILE&utm_campaign=GEO+FENCING
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 48476 "www.bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_0_1 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13A404" 1.285

```
^<HOST>.*"(GET|HEAD|POST).*HTTP.*".*bs.serving-sys.com.*".*$
```

Я использую такую регулярку, можно сказать она не "жёсткая", то есть `referrer` может быть и в поле `User-agent`, и она тогда сработает, но это очень маловероятно.

Хотелось бы узнать, какой путь правильный, писать её чётко определённую, так чтобы и дату проверять, и сайт. Но это лишняя проверка, я считаю. Ведь может быть такое, что она не пройдет, в то время как имя `referrer`-a будет совпадающим и мы не получим срабатывания из-за того, что имя сайта или дата, или любая друга дополнительная проверка не прошла.

P.S.: для `<HOST>` уже определена группа, котоая парсит *IP*-адрес.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если двойные кавычки во всех строках аналогично стоят, то вместо `.*` следует поставить `[^"]*` (любое количество символов, не двойных кавычек).
2. И дополнительную проверку на наличие только пробелов или цифр между целью запроса и реферерром `[\s\d]+`

   ```
   /^<HOST>.*"(?=GET|HEAD|POST)[^"]*HTTP[^"]*"[\s\d]+"[^"]*bs\.serving-sys\.com[^"]*".*$/
   ```

Пример https://regex101.com/r/wG8rB9/1 (в тестовые строки в начало дописал `<HOST>`, чтобы регулярку не менять)

Comment: Да, кавычки везде одинаковые `"`

Я тоже думал об этом. Насчет `[^"]*`
Но смотри, вот например у нас HTTP всегда стоит внутри строки, в кавычках. То есть выходит что используя `.*HTTP` мы словим всё, и упрёмся в HTTP как в стопор?

Comment: `(?=)` Зачем эта группа? Ты имеел ввиду группировку `(?:)` без обратной связи чтоб память не занимать?

Comment: 1. Да, вместо `(?=)` можно поставить `(?:)`. 2. До `HTTP` можно поставить и `.*`, и проверки `.*"(?=GET|HEAD|POST)[^"]*` можно убрать вообще. После `HTTP` нужно оставлять все `[^"]*`.

Comment: Значит ли это выражение `^<HOST>.*"(GET|HEAD|POST)` что я не словлю никакую другую кавычку, кроме как ту, которая предшествует `(GET|HEAD|POST)` ? Ведь эта группа сразу за кавычкой идёт. Или я регулярка сначала словит всё до самой последней кавычки, а затем увидев `(GET|HEAD|POST)` вернётся назад и словит лишь ту кавычку, которая предшествует `(GET|HEAD|POST)` ? Если это так, то это лишние операции и тогда я понимаю зачем `^<HOST>[^"]*"(GET|HEAD|POST)` мы пишем.

Comment: @MishaPolitaev, `.*"(GET|HEAD|POST)` тут поймаем первое вхождение кавычки и одного из трех слов или, если такого не будет, то **пройдем до конца строки**. Если использовать `[^"]*"`, то дойдем до первой кавычки и если дальше нет одного из трех слов, то все.